# Retrieve columns multiple times using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

In Access 2007 I have a table named `Registars` with a list of people and a table named `Related`.

`Registars` has a Primary key of `Reg_ID` and a field of `Reg_Surname` and a field of `Reg_Forename`.

`Related` table has a field of `Reg_Person_ID` and a field of `Rel_Person_ID` where both are primary keys (or combination key) a third field is `relation_Type`, i.e. cousin, sister etc.

What I am trying to write is a SQL script that will interrogate these two tables and using each record in the Related table output the ID of the first person and then their Forename then their surname then the second persons ID then thgeir forename then their surname.  That is;

```
Reg_Person_ID Reg_Forename Reg_Surname Rel_Person_ID Reg_Forename Reg_Surname
```

So far what I have tried using SQL hasn't worked.  Below is a screen dump of the two tables with data and the desired output.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    reg.Reg_Person
    ,reg.Reg_Forename
    ,reg.Reg_Surname
    ,rel.Rel_Person_ID
    ,rr.Reg_Forename AS Rel_Forename
    ,rr.Reg_Surname AS Rel_Surname
    ,rel.Relation_Type
FROM    
    Registrars reg
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Related rel
    ON reg.Reg_ID = rel.Reg_Person_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Registrars rr
    ON rel.Rel_Person_ID = rr.Reg_ID
```